# dotnet ef dbcontext scaffol Mac Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation-EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework, macos, .net-6.0

Hola amigos estoy intentando hacer un  **dotnet ef dbcontext scaffol**  en un **Macbook Pro** utlizando **.net 6** y **Minimal Api**, pero estoy teniendo este error tras usar el siguiente commando:

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=[server];user id=[user];password=[password];database=[mydb]" MySql.EntityFrameworkCoreMySql.EntityFrameworkCore -c [mydb] -o DbContext -f -v

a contunuacion

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

```
Using assembly 'JMCONNECT'.
Using startup assembly 'JMCONNECT'.
Using application base '/Users/eduardorodriguez/Projects/JMCONNECT/JMCONNECT/bin/Debug/net6.0'.
Using content root '/Users/eduardorodriguez/Projects/JMCONNECT/JMCONNECT/'.
Using root namespace 'JMCONNECT'.
Using project directory '/Users/eduardorodriguez/Projects/JMCONNECT/JMCONNECT/'.
Using data directory '/Users/eduardorodriguez/Projects/JMCONNECT/JMCONNECT/bin/Debug/net6.0/'.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext..ctor(OperationExecutor executor, IOperationResultHandler resultHandler, IDictionary args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor.Execute(String operationName, Object resultHandler, IDictionary arguments)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.InvokeOperationImpl(String operationName, IDictionary arguments)
   at 

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.InvokeOperation[TResult](String operation, IDictionary arguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles)
   at 

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DbContextScaffoldCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at 

Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta ejecutar este comando `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold -f -v` ese `-v` sirve para ver a detalle lo que se está ejecutando, de ahí sale información interesante.

Comment: @fredyfx me da esto
error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design from 6.0.9 to 5.0.3. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
/Users/eduardorodriguez/Projects/JMCON/JMCON/JMCON.csproj : error NU1605:  JMCON -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.9 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (>= 6.0.9) 
/Users/eduardorodriguez/Projects/JMCON/JMCON/JMCON.csproj : error NU1605:  JMCON -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (>= 5.0.3)

Build FAILED.

Comment: Revisa dónde está el nuget de versión `5.0.3` y lo actualizas a `6.0.9`

Comment: @fredyfx funciono pero este error persiste Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext..ctor(OperationExecutor

Comment: Edita la pregunta y coloca los nuevos datos.

Comment: @fredyfx ya agregue la nueva info , pero el error parce muy similar al original

Comment: Que sea similar o diferente, es buen indicador. Por otro lado... lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Especialmente punto 2 y 4.

Comment: @fredyfx agregue mas detalles

Comment: Ponele voluntad che... Incluye las clases que haces uso, tu DB Context y todo lo que haga falta para reproducir tu escenario, si estás usando el enfoque de DB First, coloca las tablas de tu BD también. Por cierto, aquí otra lectura sugerida: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.